# Request: When closing a question as duplicate, to show all the linked questions

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates

When people post "This question is a duplicate of XXX", would it be possible for the selections shown when we decide to close a question as duplicate, to also show XXX? This could be easily done by simply showing all the linked questions as possible candidates, instead of just the 'top related' ones.

Comment: Or generally poll for links from the comments.